# Eosjs. How to add new key to JsSignatureProvider

Tags: eosjs

Here:

```
var privateKeys = [...];
var sp = new JsSignatureProvider(privateKeys);
var key = 'ASG...';
sp.addKey(key);  // (1)
```

I want to add new key to `JsSignatureProvider`, but I can't find method like (1).
Is it exists?

How can we add new key to `JsSignatureProvider` after it already been constructed?

Thank you!

ps. We don't use `JsSignatureProvider` in production code. Just for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add public key to JsSignatureProvider.availableKeys (`string[]`) and private key to JsSignatureProvider.keys (`Map<string,string>`) by public key.

```
var { Numeric } = require('eosjs');
var { JsSignatureProvider } = require('eosjs/dist/eosjs-jssig');
var ecc = require('eosjs-ecc');

var privateKeys = ['...'];
var sp = new JsSignatureProvider(privateKeys);
var key ='...';

const pub = Numeric.convertLegacyPublicKey(ecc.PrivateKey.fromString(key).toPublic().toString());
sp.keys.set(pub, key);
sp.availableKeys.push(pub);
```

Comment: Didn't know about 'Numeric.convertLegacyPublicKey' method. Thank you!